# How to fetch results from two tables? (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I retrieve results from two tables in MySQLi using the object oriented way?

I am trying to fetch user information for $stmt2 from $stmt. $stmt loads perfectly but $stmt2 doesn't because it isn't getting the results.

Here's the code for it:

```
<?php

            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `id`, `kills` FROM `rp_stats` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 6'))
            {
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $kills);

                while($stmt->fetch())
                {
                    if ($stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `username`, `look`, `online` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?"))
                    {
                    $stmt2->bind_param("i", $id);
                    $stmt2->execute();
                    $stmt2->bind_result($id, $username, $look, $online);
                    $user = $stmt2->get_result();
                    }

                    global $stmt2;

                    echo '<div class="leaderboardWrap">
                    <div class="userAvatar" style="float: left;width: 50px;display: inline-block;height: 50px;background-image: url(\'https://www.habbo.nl/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='. $look . '&size=m&headonly=1\');"></div>
                    <div class="leaderboardContainer">
                    <p style="padding-top: 6px;"><span class="username-rainbow"><a ng-click="progress()" href="/user/' . $username . '">' . $username . '</a></span></p>
                    <p style="margin-top: -9px;"><i>$' . formatWithSuffix($credits) . ' cash</i></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }

                $stmt->close();
            }
        ?>
```

I want it to show 6 different users based on the user stat as the left image shows, but instead, I am getting the right image.

[image: Wanted result] [image: current result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using same column names in different tables, so a join conflicts by default. That's why you must use aliases, like so:

```
SELECT s.id, s.kills, u.username
FROM rp_stats s
INNER JOIN users u ON s.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY s.kills DESC LIMIT 6
```

**Note!** that I use `user_id`. This is the foreign key (reference) from `rp_stats` to `users`. I mean it's not correct to compare users.id with rp_stats.id. Using this construction, a user can always have max. 1 stat. You generate more flexibility to user a `user_id` column, which references to the user table.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `inner join` in database to minimize fetch process of data:

```
SELECT `id`, `kills` FROM `rp_stats` 
INNER JOIN users ON rp_stats.id = user.id 
ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: This is not the right answer, because id is ambigious. Further are you comparing rp_stats.id with users.id?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT RS.`id`, RS.`kills`, US.`id`, US.`username`, US.`look`, US.`online` FROM rp_stats RS, users US WHERE US.`id`=RS.`id` ORDER BY RS.`kills` DESC LIMIT 6";
```

A normalized query could help out.